# Timer and Thread Questions

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I have the following code: 
Controller.java:

```
package Test;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Controller extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener {
    private Robot robot = new Robot();
    @Override
    public void init() {
        setSize(800, 480);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {

        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(17);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ... Do Stuff ....
    }
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.destroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.stop();
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL:
            robot.fire();
            break;
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Robot.java

```
package Test;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Robot {
    private Timer timer = new Timer(); 
    private int firerate = 2500; 
    public Robot() {
    }
    public void fire() {
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                    System.out.println("2 Seconds!");
                  }
                }, firerate);
        }
    }
```

I have a thread which runs updates in intervals of 17 ms.

In the Robot class I make the robot do something 2.5 seconds each time after CTRL is pressed

My questions are as follows: 
Since Thread is used in the Main class and Timer is used in the Robot Class (both implement run() function):

a. Do those two methods interrupt each other?

b. Are there any pros / cons in using those two together?

c. Is there a way to use Thread for scheduling tasks such as this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "...which updates in intervals of 17 ms"  The Controller.run() method in your example does not show a loop.  It sleeps _once_ for 17 milliseconds, and then it does stuff.

Comment: If you want to perform a task every 17 milliseconds, then you probably don't want to sleep for 17 milliseconds in the loop.  That will wait for 17 millis between the _end_ of one execution and the start of the next.  Not only will the period be longer than 17 milliseconds, it also may be variable.  (depends on the task).  Consider using ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a. Do those two methods interrupt each other?

No. They are both executed in a different thread. They live their own life.

> b. Are there any pros / cons in using those two together?

Not really. You want concurrent tasks, and that is what you have.

Try to favor `ExecutorService` (built from [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)) to run your `Runnable` in order to isolate the tasks and the way they are concurrently executed.

> c. Is there a way to use Thread for scheduling tasks such as this?

Yes, using a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(controller, 0, 17, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```